# replacement length zero R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some web data and put it into a dataframe for future use. Some of the values in some columns are NA; I'd like those cells to have NA or some text. Here's the for loop I'm working with:

```
    extra <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(main.node), ncol = 2))
    for (i in 1:length(main.node)){
      extra[i,1] <- main.node[[i]]$data$author
      extra[i,2] <- main.node[[i]]$data$author_flair_text
      }
```

The issue is that some values of `author_flair_text` are non-existent (the author column is working fine). For instance, calling
 `main.node[[4]]$data$author_flair_text` returns `NULL`.

I'm getting the error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 2, value = NULL) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Basically, I need the for loop to fill in missing information. Is there a way to convert NULL to "NULL" within the for loop?

In case this helps, here's where `main.node` comes from:

```
raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(URL, warn = FALSE)), 
                        error = function(e) NULL)
main.node = raw_data[[2]]$data$children
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Use an `if` statement, using `is.null` to determine if the value is `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Warning I didn't run it, I just wrote it so there may be a typo:

```
extra <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(main.node), ncol = 2))
for (i in 1:length(main.node)){
  extra[i,1] <- main.node[[i]]$data$author
  temp <- main.node[[i]]$data$author_flair_text
  if(is.null(temp)){
    temp <- "NULL"
  }
  extra[i,2] <- temp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse()` construct here. It has a `test` argument (for the condition), a `yes` argument (the value if test is true), and a `no` argument (the value if the test is false).

In your case, it will look something like this:

```
temp <- main.node[[i]]$data$author_flair_text
extra[i,2] <- ifelse(is.null(temp), "your_null_indicator", temp)
```